# Solid evidence or user test experience for Badge Notifications

Tags: usability-testing

Has anyone looked into the effectiveness of those **red notification badges** on the top navigation of websites like facebook and google plus? I know it's useful for Facebook, but I'm wondering if it's already **thought of as banner blindness** elsewhere.

Has anyone run actual tests on it or read an article by some usability authority?

Comment: No research, just the heuristics for *Indicators, Validations, and Notifications* by Nielsen Norman Group, here: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/indicators-validations-notifications/

Answer (score 1):

As you've asked for an article by a usability authority, I would like to quote a couple of paragraphs found in **[Handbook of Human-Computer Interaction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444886737)**:

> ### Color Emphasis
>
> Color emphasis suggests using strong contrast in value and chroma to
>   focus the operator's attention on critical information. ***High chroma
>   red alerts seem to aid faster response*** than yellow or yellow-orange if
>   brightness is equal, but this also depends on background colors.

The following is a special case but still makes a lot of sense:

> ### Code Economy: Sequencing
>
> To code a large set of colors, use the spectral sequence: red, orange,
>   yellow, green, blue and violet. Frnacine Frome, a human factors
>   researcher shown that CAD/CAM viewers see a spectral order as a
>   natural one and would select red, green, and blue as intuitive choices
>   for the front, middle and back layers, respectively, when viewing a
>   multi-layer display.